# How to enlarge the marker on mouseover in mapbox gl js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

i have 3 markers and when i hover on the marker, i want the marker to get enlarged. can anyone help me to solve this. I had tried to change the pointer on mouseover but not getting how to enlarge marker on hover.

TS:

```
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmFrc2hpdGhhMTkiLCJhIjoiY2pjcHl1YW5wMjR5czJ6bzdqdjZrbDRzeSJ9.OOqu6zVyNsXavzCsYoBdPA';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: 'maps',
          style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
          center: [12.568337,55.676098],
          zoom: 9
    });



  map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
      "id": "points1",
      "type": "circle",
      "paint":{
        "circle-radius":10,
        "circle-color":'rgba(55,148,179,1)'    
      },
        "source": {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features":  [{
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {},
              "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [12.568337,55.676098]
              }
            }]
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there are two ways to do this.

1. Add a unique `id` property to each of your Features. Create a new `hover` layer with larger circle-radius and a filter initially to select none of the `id`'s. Then on `mouseover` set the filter on that `hover` layer with the `id` of the feature returned from the `mouseover` event. See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/
2. Create a new `hover` layer, and use setData to move features in and out of this layer rather than by using a filter.
3. Use Data Driven Styles on the `circle-radius`, setting it to 30 if the id matches the hovered feature, or 10 otherwise. https://bl.ocks.org/andrewharvey/681739a659c6e9d2b180dac310e24ff6

Comment: i updated my question, please let me know whether that is correct? i am not getting my requirement

Comment: I wouldn't be adding a different layer for each Feature. Unless you need performance I'd stick my my first suggestion just like the Mapbox example.